# What is the difference between include tags and embed tags in expressionengine?

Tags: expressionengine

The discussion forum module for expression engine uses {include:file} tags in its templates like in forum_themes/developer/forum_index/main_forum_list.html:

```
{include:table_heading}
{include:table_rows}
{include:table_footer}
```

I've searched for the include tag documentation but I can't find it anywhere? What is the include tag and when/where should it be used? Is it specific to the discussion forum module?

Comment: Those are probably just "snippets", with a strange naming convention.

Answer (score 9):

I cannot speak to the scope of the {include:file} tag but for most purposes the {embed} tag is what you will be using in ExpressionEngine to include/embed other bits of code.

Other alternatives, depending on the information you would like to include in your page, are the [Snippets](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/snippets.html), Global Variables, or for more complex information [LowVariables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables)

Answer (score 8):

Forums are quite difficult to customize and there is very little documentation but the include for forums essentially acts as an embed.

For customizing your forums I would recommend looking at using at the [Scaffold Theme](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/scaffold) on Devot:ee

Answer (score 7):

It should also be noted that {include:file} only work in the forum template code and most standard EE tags (such as the {embed} tag) don't work in the forum templates. Why? I don't know, but dems da rules. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no documentation on the {include:XXX} tag as it is only used in the Forum templates.

You will never use this tag in normal EE templates. In EE templates you will use an {embed="group/template"} tag or a Snippet depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to embedding templates within each other, you can also create shared layouts for your templates. A layout can be thought of as a wrapping template or a reverse embed. To use a template you use the {layout=""} tag at the top of your template:

{layout="template_group/template"}